# Django, How to pass HTML form values to URL upon form submission?

Tags: html, django

The project have url as follows,

```
 path('post/<str:state>/',SearchView.as_view(),name='search-data')
```

I have a HTML form, upon filling and submitting it supposed to pass filled form data to URL.

```
<form action={% url 'search-data'%} method="get" >
      {% csrf_token %}
     
      <input type="text"  name="fname">
```

But it does not work as supposed to be.

When form submitted it gives below URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7Burl?csrfmiddlewaretoken=2RZfZ4cxLB...
```

Comment: You don't have any submit button and your url should be ``{% url 'search-data' %}`` instead of ``{url 'search-data'}``

Comment: added and edited but same error,

Comment: I have more params in URL to pass, if I follow you , how can I grab url param. value at view  functions ? like follow state = self.kwargs['state']

Comment: Hello @Almiracontracting check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to pass `<str:state>` argument in your urlpatterns just pass `path('post/search',SearchView.as_view(),name='search-data')` or whatever you want but problem is when you pass an argument like this `post/<str:state>/` than you have to specify that in your form action also
like this `{% url 'search-data' state %}` initialy you don't have any state so that's why you have to get the state name from your form so finnaly your code look like this

```
<form action={% url 'search-data'%} method="get" >
      {% csrf_token %}
     
      <input type="text"  name="fname">  
      <input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```

and than in your views you've to get it from `request.GET` method like this

```
def search(request):
    state = request.GET.get('fname', None)
    .... do whatever you want 
    return response_or_data
```